# Validation of custom labels value in a lightning web component using jest

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm building a lightning web component and when adding unit tests, I'm facing the issue that the labels are not rendered in the element when the test is running. What's the best approach to handle this?

Comment: LWC module name of the label will be returned (eg.`c.Greeting_Label`). It's possible to mock the label value. Can you please elaborate why would you need to do that? Labels can be translated, or can changed. Because of that the state of your component should not depend on label values.

Comment: Yes, makes sense, I could validate it against c.Label_Name and leave it as is.

Comment: Personally, I would just check that my element containing label is `not.toBeNull();`. In LWC import statements you can't reference non-existing label anyway (`import iDontExist from '@salesforce/label/c.I_Dont_Exist';` would return an error when deploying).

Comment: @Michal Varva you should move your comment to an answer so it can be the accepted answer for others with similar issues that end up here.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't test label values. It's not considered as a good practice. Labels can change overtime (or even get translated).

When you reference Custom Label in Lightning Web Component like this:

```
import helloWorld from '@salesforce/label/c.Hello_World';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  helloWorldText = helloWorld;
}
```

```
<template>
  <p>{helloWorldText}</p>
</template>
```

Instead of actual orgs label value, you will get JavaScript module name.

Property `helloWorldText` will contain `c.Hello_World` in component test.

```
const helloWorldText = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('p');
console.log(helloWorldText) // Output: c.Hello_World
```

---

`@salesforce` scoped imports will handle for you the actual existence of referenced object.
If you would try to use non-existing Custom Label, you wouldn't be able to deploy (compile) your Component JavaScript file.

If you really wish to change Custom Label value in component test, take a look into [`lwc-recipes`](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/3036d3f3e3eed938fb70850c38c96b9c0f401fe7/force-app/test/jest-mocks) Jest mock examples.